# What is the purpose of readstream() in the following code

Tags: android, c++, opencv

What is the purpose of the `readstream()` function in the following code?

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);
}
finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();   
}
```

The code is from [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Comment: Can you be specific to the question? So, that other engineers can answer you easily.

Comment: a stream is like a pipe you can use to read data from. readStream in your case is a function (you?) have created to read stuff once you setup the pipe.

Comment: It's a (fictitious) function that reads a stream. It's there for illustration purposes.